# What is the meaning of 의전서열?

Tags: vocabulary, translation, single-word-request

I know the meaning of each word is

서열 序列
rank, grade

의전 儀典
ceremony, formality, protocol, etiquette as practiced on diplomatic occasions

But i couldn't find the best term in english

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You call it the order of precedence. Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_precedence),

> Order of precedence is a sequential hierarchy of nominal importance of persons. Most often it is used in the context of people by many organizations and governments, for very formal and state occasions, especially where diplomats are present.

Comment: And I'm quite surprised that "의전 서열" is not registered as a compound word in the two big Dictionaries (Standard / Korea Univ.).